# Discretizing Continuous Outcomes: good examples?

Tags: classification, modeling, discrete-data

My continuous dependent variable has a lot of error in it. Hence, I was thinking of discretizing it, to reduce the error for my modeling effort. But firstly, the main focus of my modeling effort are the following: 1) Determine whether there is any predictive power in the set of independent variables (IVs) that I have; 2) If (1) is true, ie the IVs have predictive power, I'd like to do feature selection: I have ~40 IVs, many of them are correlated (num. of observations is 150). I would like to select a parsimonious set (4 or 5 IVs) that predict the DV to some level.

In this context, I found this para from the "Applied predictive modeling" (by Max Kuhn & Kjell Johnson, 2013) to be relevant:

"A second common reason for wanting to categorize a continuous response
is that the scientist may believe that the continuous response contains a high
degree of error, so much so that only the response values in either extreme
of the distribution are likely to be correctly categorized. If this is the case,
then the data can be partitioned into three categories, where data in either
extreme are classified generically as positive and negative, while the data in
the midrange are classified as unknown or indeterminate. The middle category
can be included as such in a model **(or specifically excluded from the model
tuning process)** to help the model more easily discriminant between the two
categories."

(See section 20.4, "Discretizing Continuous Outcomes", at the end; pg 533).

In my case, I think that the strategy outlined in the boldface part above (where the middle category has been excluded from the model tuning process) makes sense. That way, we are defining two well-separated classes. These well-separated classes help me "analyze the set of IVs" by using a model (so to speak) and do feature selection. By the way, I am planning to use glmnet/lasso for the feature selection.

My question to you is: Can you please give me two to three good references (ie, journal papers) where dependent variable discretization has been justified in this way?

Thanks in advance!
R.

Comment: Many sources advise against this emphatically.  You won't remove error by coarsening your variable: you increase it.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for that. I have edited the question after giving it some thought. Can you please respond again?

Comment: The point is elementary. Suppose I count with error and my values are integers like 0, 1 up. How I am better off rounding to even numbers or to the indicator above or below 5? I am just discarding information. Frank Harrell's _Regression modeling strategies_ (Springer 2015) says more and gives formal references.

Answer (score 3):

The quote you cite seems to be in the context of classification, where you know that there are only 2 classes and the values of the dependent variable are proxies for class membership, rather than regression. Even for that application, discretizing the dependent variable is a questionable tactic. For your application, which seems to be predicting values of a continuous dependent variable, I doubt that you will find many reputable references that justify discretizing it to start. Continuous transformations of dependent and independent variables often can help a model, but it's hard to envision a case where you are better off breaking your continuous variable into a few discrete categories. You throw away too much information in the process.

For your broader goal, think carefully about what you are trying to accomplish with feature selection. With a reasonably sized data set 40 IVs are not necessarily a lot. If many of them are inter-correlated, any selection of a small set of 4 or 5 by LASSO or other methods will vary substantially among data samples, as you can verify by bootstrapping. For predictions you may be much better off including all your IVs with ridge regression, which provides appropriate penalization while treating correlated variables together.

Comment: your point is good. Btw, my n=150. I will check by bootstrapping as to how much variation there is...Thanks!

Comment: For a continuous outcome variable, the usual rule of thumb is that your 150 cases would limit you to only considering about 10 predictor variables without penalization. Stepwise selection is generally unwise, particularly in this type of case. LASSO and ridge regression both provide penalization. Alternatively, based on subject-matter knowledge you could try combining groups of correlated predictors into individual predictors (without using the outcome variable to guide the combination) to cut down on the number of predictors. Much depends on how you want to use your model.